# Keep int variables values from dataReader c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, oracle11g, datareader

I don't have much experience with C# but I am trying to make a simple windows forms app with personal finances.
So, I have 2 dataReader (I am using the Oracle provider), and the sql (oracle table) commands that select only 2 columns from a table, only with 1 value, mainly income 1 and income2 and the sum of all values from a specific month.

the sql strings look like this:

```
strSQL_sel_income1 = "select DISTINCT categorie,SUM(suma) from financiar where main_categ='income' and categorie IN ('income1') and EXTRACT(month FROM data)=" + luna_income + "  Group by categorie";
        strSQL_sel_income2 = "select DISTINCT categorie,SUM(suma) from financiar where main_categ='income' and categorie IN ('Income2') and EXTRACT(month FROM data)=" + luna_income + "  Group by categorie";
```

the "luna_income" value is taken from a combobox where I select a specific month.
The problem is when I try to declare an Int variable from the values I get with data reader and these variables are not kept outside the while statement... dr_income1/2 being the dataReader

```
if (dr_income1.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr_income1.Read())
                {
                       label26.Text = dr_income1.GetString(0) + ": " + dr_income1.GetInt32(1) + "\n";
                    int suma_income1 = dr_incomei1.GetInt32(1);

                }

            }
            else
            {
                label26.Text = "No info;
            }
```

so, I have two similar data readers and two int variables suma_income1 and suma_income2. If I try to make a sum of them, outside the WhIle codes, I get a zero value. Where should I declare the two variables and how to keep their values?

```
int suma_income_total = suma_income1 + suma_income2;
            label29.Text = "Income total: " + suma_income_total;
```

The suma_income_total is ZERO!!!

```
dr_income1 = cm1.ExecuteReader();
dr_income2 = cm2.ExecuteReader();
  label26.Text = "";
  label28.Text = "";

            if (dr_income1.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr_income1.Read())
                {
                        label26.Text = dr_income1.GetString(0) + ": " + dr_income1.GetInt32(1) + "\n";
                    int suma_income1 = dr_income1.GetInt32(1);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                label26.Text = "No info";
            }
            
            if (dr_income2.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr_income2.Read())
                {
                 label28.Text = dr_income2.GetString(0) + ": " + dr_income2.GetInt32(1) + "\n";
                    int suma_income2 = dr_income2.GetInt32(1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                label28.Text = "no info";
            }
                   
            int suma_income_total = suma_income1 + suma_income2;
            label29.Text = "income total: " + suma_income_total;
            
            dr_income2.Close();
            dr_income1.Close();
```

Comment: Could you publish the whole data reader code with 2 data readers please. I can see only one data reader.

Comment: I edited the first post, and added the two data readers! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I put some changes in your code. It is not ideal since there are several much simple ways. But it is ok as workaround:

```
dr_income1 = cm1.ExecuteReader();
dr_income2 = cm2.ExecuteReader();
  label26.Text = "";
  label28.Text = "";

var suma_income1 =0;
var suma_income2 =0;

            if (dr_income1.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr_income1.Read())
                {
                        label26.Text = dr_income1.GetString(0) + ": " + dr_income1.GetInt32(1) + "\n";
                     suma_income1 += dr_income1.GetInt32(1);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                label26.Text = "No info";
            }
            
            if (dr_income2.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr_income2.Read())
                {
                 label28.Text = dr_income2.GetString(0) + ": " + dr_income2.GetInt32(1) + "\n";
                   suma_income2 += dr_income2.GetInt32(1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                label28.Text = "no info";
            }
                   
            int suma_income_total = suma_income1 + suma_income2;
            label29.Text = "income total: " + suma_income_total;
            
            dr_income2.Close();
            dr_income1.Close();
```

Comment: @Livix If this answer helped you, you can [vote on / accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).